# Android can't debug after adding certain permissions

Tags: android, xml, debugging, android-manifest, nfc

I added some NFC permissions to my app and now it no longer enters into debug mode. It just says "installed on device... done!"

```
 [2011-10-08 20:58:37 - myApp] Automatic Target Mode: using device '3433254FAA1500EC'
 [2011-10-08 20:58:37 - myApp] Uploading myApp.apk onto device '3433254FAA1500EC'
 [2011-10-08 20:58:37 - myApp] Installing myApp.apk...
 [2011-10-08 20:58:39 - myApp] Success!
 [2011-10-08 20:58:39 - myApp] /myApp/bin/myApp.apk installed on device
 [2011-10-08 20:58:39 - myApp] Done!
```

it happens whenever I have added this to the manifest:

`<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />`

this the xml around it

```
  <activity android:name="Home"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


        </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc"
            />

    </activity>
```

I want to be able to debug with my breakpoints, why is this being prevented?

Comment: if you remove this permission does the device go back into debug mode?

Comment: yes, I can debug it then. For the record, the DEVICE is always in debug mode, the program just won't start its intent, it only installs, I have to pick up the device and click the application manually, but of course when I do this the application isn't in debug mode it is simply running. If I cut out that one permission and click debug, the application opens up in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting the TECH_DISCOVERED in its own , take it out of the list with MAIN and LAUNCHER

```
<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

<intent-filter>'
```

I did it that way and am able to debug my NFC app.

Comment: You would need `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` with TECH_DISCOVERED. Otherwise the intent filter would not match.